# Wordpress Visual Editor broken

Tags: wordpress, editor

The visual editor is broken in Wordpress. THe editor is only HTML mode. The tabs to switch between VISUAL / HTML modes are hidden. I already tried deactivate all plugins but not working. WP 3.5.1.  [image]

Comment: let me know if its work check below solution

Comment: This is usually due to a broken javascript file. Can you open up Chrome/FF and check to see if you have any JS errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi this exact problem happen with you can fix by going to

users >> Profile >> Visual Editor uncheck check box

Thankyou

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-remove-visual-editor-mode-in-wordpress/

Comment: Never too late to tell the old story : Thank you so much you saved my day in june! Was working for a client on a site I did not know. I knew this option of course but I was blinded by another crazy theme bug (big image broke the entire editor) so after resolving the first bug after few hours of struggle I could not think of a so simple origin :D Thank you again / Can not vote for you sorry / Not enough points :D