# Visual Editor not available in Wordpress, not even tabs

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

In Wordpress, I am only seeing the html editor when I try to edit a page or post or custom post type.

Not only that but there are no options to even switch (so the tabs are missing too)

What I have tried:

1. I can confirm there are no JavaScript errors
2. There are no WordPress errors
3. I load www.example.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php and am seeing the code
4. I have deactivated all plugins

Some notes:

1. when I search for "mce" in firebug there is only one reference to it, there are IDs or classes using that term
2. I do see    `<div class="wp-editor-tabs"></div>` but it is exactly like that, i.e. empty inside, whereas on a working version this div is filled the html for the tabs

Thank you

Comment: There should be asked on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Does this apply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217022/wordpress-visual-editor-broken?rq=1? Did you update or install WP recently?

Comment: I dont believe it !! Thanks for that, I had done plenty of searches and didnt find that question! Cheers

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: @j08691 yes it did, feel free to answer , or mark as duplicate.